# listview object to custom dialog box

Tags: android

I have some data in listview from list view I want to send my one field to dialogbox

```
l=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdailog);
    dialog.setTitle("Fill This Form");


    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    EditText DrName,Patient_mobile,Username;
    DrName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.DortorName);
    DrName.setHint("sss");

    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    dialog.show();
```

my log cat

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.example.finddoctor.Doctor_Names$2.onItemClick(Doctor_Names.java:128)
                                                                            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
                                                                            at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
                                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Plese post your logcat here @Naveed Abbas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that EditText `DrName` is part of dialog and you are accessing it from activity layout so it gives null pointer exception,therefore
Change

```
            DrName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.DortorName);
```

to

```
            DrName=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.DortorName);
```

Comment: tnx alot how did i missed that :( :(